# Replace column names by iterating through names and numbers

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am trying to change all the column names of my datafile.

I would like every column name to be consisting of 'V', a number, '_', 'name' so that I get the following:

```
V1_category, V1_pleasant, V1_unpleasant, V1_painful, V1_threat, V1_arousal, V2_category, V2_pleasant, V2_unpleasant, V2_painful, V2_threat, V2_arousal, V3_category, V3_pleasant, V3_unpleasant and this repeats until V45.
```

So somehow I have to paste V with the numbers 1:45 and the following names `["category", "pleasant", "unpleasant", "painful", "threat", "arousal"]` so that it's `[Vnumber_name]`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.Series.groupby.cumcount` with `str.cat`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("ABABABAB"))
s = df.columns.to_series()
s2 = s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1)
df.columns = "V" + s2.astype(str).str.cat(s2.index, sep="_")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [V1_A, V1_B, V2_A, V2_B, V3_A, V3_B, V4_A, V4_B]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
column=["category", "pleasant", "unpleasant", "painful", "threat", "arousal"] 
new_columns=[['V'+str(number+1)+'_'+col for col in column] for number in range(45)]
new_columns = [item for sublist in new_columns for item in sublist]
```

Explanation: Using list comprehension in 2nd line, generate a 2d list with all required names. Then the 3rd line helps in flattening that list to 1d shape giving all new column names.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
titles = ["category", "pleasant", "unpleasant", "painful", "threat", "arousal"]
print([f"V{i}_{title}" for i in range(1,46) for title in titles])
```

Output goes like this:

```
['V1_category', 'V1_pleasant', 'V1_unpleasant', 'V1_painful', 'V1_threat', 'V1_arousal', 'V2_category', 'V2_pleasant', 'V2_unpleasant', 'V2_painful', 'V2_threat', 'V2_arousal', 'V3_category', 'V3_pleasant', 'V3_unpleasant', 'V3_painful', 'V3_threat', 'V3_arousal', 'V4_category', ... , 'V45_category', 'V45_pleasant', 'V45_unpleasant', 'V45_painful', 'V45_threat', 'V45_arousal']
```